# Python 3.7.3 and Tensorflow 15.2 runtime error

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi4

I have python 3.7.3 and Tensorflow 15.2 installed in raspberry pi 4.  When I tried to do import Tensorflow as TD, it failed to load the native Tensorflow runtimes.  I got the import error undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_current

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > > from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > > File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > > _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > > File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > > _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > > File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
> > > return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > > File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
> > > return _load(spec)
> > > ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Can you please help and advice how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.  I'm guessing it means you're missing a library of some sort.

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for your help!  Please find the full traceback error as below: